# jQuery code to set unique href attributes within list items

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, href

I have a list of 200 items. Each `<li>` contains an `<h3>` tag with text string of a unique phone number. Each `<li>` also contains `<a>` tag, parent of the `<h3>`. On page load, I need to set the href value of each `<a>` tag with the phone number contained within it's child `<h3>`.

**jQuery**

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var phonenumber = $(this > "h3").html();
    $(this).attr("href", "phonenumber");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <h1>Altman, Jennifer, Phd</h1>
    <a href="">
        <h3>617-999-5054</h3>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) as shown:

```
$("a").each(function() {
   var phonenumber = $(this).find("h3").text();
   $(this).attr("href", phonenumber);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmzRV/636/)